# Finding the derivative of an exponential function without the chain rule

Tags: calculus, derivatives, exponential-function

Given $f(x) = a^x$, one can compute the derivative of $f(x)$ using the chain rule quickly by noticing that

$f(x) = a^x = \left(e^{ln(a)}\right)^x$.

But how would you go about computing the derivative of $f(x)$ without the chain rule, with just the $f'(x) = \lim_\limits{h \to 0} \frac{f(x + h) - f(x)}{h}$ or the $f'(x) = \lim_\limits{x \to a} \frac{f(x) - f(a)}{x - a}$ definition of a derivative and the fact that $\lim_\limits{h \to 0} \frac{e^h - 1}{h} = 1$?

$f'(x) = \lim_\limits{h \to 0} \frac{a^{x + h} - a^x}{h} = a^x \cdot \lim_\limits{h \to 0} \frac{a^h - 1}{h} = a^x \cdot \lim_\limits{h \to 0} \frac{\left(e^{ln(a)}\right)^h - 1}{h} = a^x \cdot \lim_\limits{h \to 0} \frac{(e^h)^{ln(a)} - 1}{h}$.

How would you proceed from here?

Comment: @d_b all the sources I looked at used the chain rule for this so I was curious if there is a way to do it without the chain rule. 
For problems that are designed to make you use the power or quotient rule, you can always use the limit definition without the power or quotient rule, so I wondered if it would be a possibility here too

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a way that uses our knowledge that $\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\mathrm e^h-1}{h}=1$.

At some point in the calculation you demonstrate, we get to the part where we need to evaluate

$$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\left(\mathrm e^{\ln(a)}\right)^h-1}{h}.$$

Here we can use $(\mathrm{e}^{\ln a})^h=\mathrm e^{h\ln a}$ and substitute $u:=h\ln a$ and note that $u\to0\Leftrightarrow h\to0$. So we are left evaluating

$$\begin{align}\lim_{u\to0}\frac{\mathrm e^u-1}{\frac{u}{\ln a}}&=\lim_{u\to0}\ln(a)\frac{\mathrm e^u-1}{u}\\
&=\ln a\lim_{u\to0}\frac{\mathrm e^u-1}{u}\\
&=\ln (a)\cdot 1\\
&=\ln (a).
\end{align}$$

Comment: I assume in the first sentence you mean that the limit is equal to $1$, not $0$.

Comment: @ccroth Of course! Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Here is a way to show $a^x$ has derivative $\ln(a) \cdot a^x$ without using chain rule. It uses the series expansion of $e^x$.

Since $a^x = e^{x \ln(a)}$, we have:
$$
a^x = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(x\ln(a))^n}{n!}.
$$
We can take the derivative term by term (using your favorite convergence theorem), which yields:
$$
\frac{d}{dx} a^x = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{nx^{n-1} \ln(a)^n}{n!}.
$$
Now we make the very important observation that the first term (when $n=0$) is zero. Hence, we can index starting from $n = 1$ and cancel out the $n$ in the numerator:
$$
\frac{d}{dx} a^x = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^{n-1}\ln(a)^n}{(n-1)!} = \ln(a) \cdot \sum^\infty_{n=1} \frac{x^{n-1}\ln(a)^{n-1}}{(n-1)!},
$$
noting we can pull out the factor of $\ln(a)$ from every term now. But the last sum can now be re-indexed,
$$
\sum^\infty_{n=1} \frac{x^{n-1}\ln(a)^{n-1}}{(n-1)!} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n\ln(a)^n}{n!} = a^x,
$$
so in conclusion we have:
$$
\frac{d}{dx} a^x = \ln(a) \cdot a^x.
$$

Answer (score 3):

You have reduced the problem to showing $$
\ln a=\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{(e^h)^{\ln a}-1}{h}
$$
To do this, note $(e^h)^{\ln a}=e^{h\ln a}$, and make the substitution $h= h'/\ln a$. Then we obtain $$\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{(e^h)^{\ln a}-1}{h}=\lim_{h'\rightarrow 0}\frac{e^{(h'/\ln a)\ln a}-1}{h'/\ln a}=\lim_{h'\rightarrow 0}\frac{e^{h'}-1}{h'}\ln a=\ln a
$$

Answer (score 1):

So it boils down to finding this limit:

$$\lim_\limits{h \to 0} \frac{a^{h} - 1}{h}$$

Let $y=\frac{a^{h} - 1}{h}$, then $h=\frac{\ln(1+y)}{\ln a}$. Note that as $h\rightarrow0$, so does $y.$  Now substitute this value to get

$$\lim_\limits{h \to 0} \frac{a^{h} - 1}{h}=\ln a \lim_\limits{y \to 0}  \frac{y}{\ln(1+y)}=\ln a \lim_\limits{y \to 0}  \frac{1}{\frac{1}{y}\ln(1+y)}==\ln a \lim_\limits{y \to 0}  \frac{1}{{\ln(1+y)}^\frac{1}{y}}=\frac{\ln a}{\ln e}=\ln(a).$$

Note that at the end, we used the fact that $\ln$ is continuous for positive inputs and that $\lim_{y\rightarrow 0}{(1+y)}^\frac{1}{y}=e.$

Finally
$$f'(x)=a^x\lim_\limits{h \to 0} \frac{a^{h} - 1}{h}=\ln(a)\cdot a^x$$